# Setting up a report to print to specific printer

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access 2007 and I am trying to setup my report to print to a specific printer ( setup\page\use specific printer). But after I close and save the report, it goes back to the default printer.  Why is this happening?  I've never had this problem when I used Access 2003. I made sure that the designated printer is online and I successfully printed a test page.  Please advise. Thank you

Comment: I know it's one of those "is it plugged in?" questions, but are you hitting Ctrl-S to save the report after you change the printer? You likely are doing so, and are hitting the bug cited by @Remou, but if you're not, the printer change will never be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a lingering bug: http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html#Bug

There is a hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950488

From: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30502052/specific-printer-setting-not-saved-in-access-2007.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you out

http://www.mvps.org/access/reports/rpt0009.htm

You will have to set the printer to the one you want using VBA or it will just default back

Comment: The whole printer thing was updated in the 2003 version. The link applies to the 2000 version.

Comment: The PrintDevMode code should still work, but interacting with the printer device (actually introduced in A2002, not A2003) is substantially easier (though in my opinion, still not as easy as it ought to be).

Answer (score 0):

I've put together some code that gets around this bug in Access by saving the module behind the report to a text file, making your changes to the report, then re-importing the module.

I've got more information including the code here:

http://techie-tid-bits.blogspot.com/2013/09/cant-save-printer-changes-to-access.html

I hope this helps